# Regex telephone and password

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi i'm new to python and trying to figure out how to check if the format of a telephone number is a correct american number- 555-555-5555
Also to check if a given password has lower case letters, upper case letters, and a special symbol. here is what i have so far:

```
import re
inputText = raw_input("Please enter a string for testing:")
if re.match(r'(\d{3}) \D* (\d{3}) \D* (\d{4}) \D* (\d*)', inputText):
    print ('Legitimate US phone number')
else:
    print ('Error is reported')

import re
password = raw_input("Please enter a string for testing:")
if re.match(r'((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#^*=%]).{6,15})', password):
    print ('Valid Password')    
else:
    print ('Error')
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?

Answer (score 2):

To match a phone number of the form you gave

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'this is a test with 123-456-7890 a phone number'
>>> p = '\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}'
>>> re.findall(p, s)
['123-456-7890']
```

Answer (score 0):

Phone number:

```
import re
inputText = raw_input("Please enter a string for testing:")
if re.match(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', inputText):
    print ('Legitimate US phone number')
else:
    print ('Error is reported')
```

Password:

```
import re
password = raw_input("Please enter a string for testing:")
if re.match(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#^*=%]).{6,15}$', password):
    print ('Valid Password')    
else:
    print ('Error')
```

I assume all characters are in principle acceptable as a password, and guessing from your code: at least 6, and at most 15 characters. (Why would you want to limit the maximum number of characters of a password, and why to something so unreasonably short?)